# Why does my value get cascaded into every other index in my list?

Tags: c#

Got another C# question I'm not too sure about.  I know where the problem is occurring but don't understand why it would be happening.

I'm using the List.Add(); Method to add an int[] when certain conditions are met.  What I found is that when the loop finishes and I supposedly have all the values contained, all the values are the same across every index.

During debugging I found that it adds the first one correctly, but then when the second gets added it overwrites the first BUT also adds a second.  I've never seen this happen with List.Add() before, but maybe it's because I'm storing int[] objects this time?

Here's the code that adds it all in.  Looks harmless to me, but this is perhaps where I'm lacking knowledge:

```
NumbersForTriples[0] = (int)Math.Sqrt(a);
NumbersForTriples[1] = (int)Math.Sqrt(b);
NumbersForTriples[2] = (int)Math.Sqrt(c);
Triples.Add(NumbersForTriples);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are initializing NumbersForTriplets only once. You should execute a `NumbersForTriplets = new int[3]` before every sequence statements calculating your square roots and adding the array to the list, otherwise you are overwriting the same portion of memory again and again and adding the same pointer to your list many times.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.  Seems like a pretty trivial problem, but I've never ran into behavior like this (new to programming in general).  Thanks for the quick answer.